# Manage namespace library (C#)

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am trying to organize a library. My issue is that it would quickly gets very large.

This is what i have so far:

```
namespace MyLibrary {

    namespace Math {

        namespace Geometry {

            public class BezierCurve {

                //...
            };      
        }

        namespace Combinatorics {

        }
    }

    namespace Collections {

    }

    //...
}
```

Its not many lines of code now, but since BezierCurve alone is around 200 lines, creating all of the classes in the above document is not going to be the way to go.

Is it possible to somehow specify the content of BezierCurve in another document and include / refer to it in the namespace Geometry?

Comment: You can place every class in a single file. In your example you should. Why do you not use the namespace MyLibrary,Math.Geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple files can declare classes in the same namespace. There  is no requirement for a namespace to be fully defined within a single file.
You should have a file per class.
e.g. your BezierCurve would typically be in:
MyLibrary/Math/Geometry/BezierCurve.cs
and be declared within

```
namespace MyLibrary.Math.Geometry
{
    public class BezierCurve 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to have one type per file (well, with some exceptions). Thus you will have a single namespace without all this nested structure:

```
namespace MyLibrary.Math.Geometry
{
    public class BezierCurve
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to refer `BezierCurve` in another file, just add a using directive with appropriate namespace:

```
using MyLibrary.Math.Geometry;

namespace MyLibrary.Math.Combinatorics
{
    public class SomeClassFromCombinatoricsWhichUsesBezierCurve
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```